# Find all products with any tags in list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree, acts-as-taggable-on

On my spree store I need to find any product that has one or more tags in a list of tags. The tags in spree are done with the acts-as-taggable-on gem.

I have tried to do this with

```
Spree::Product.joins("spree_taggings").where("taggings.id IN (?)", list_of_tag_ids )
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

How would I be able to look up products by their tags?

Comment: can you please post the associations as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search by ID is neccessary? If you could search by names, you could use the build in scope `.tagged_with`

```
Spree::Product.tagged_with(["awesome", "cool"], :match_all => true)
```

Docs: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on#finding-tagged-objects

If search by ID is really necessary, you could grab those first of course.

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.where("id IN (?)", list_of_tag_ids).pluck(:name)
```

Comment: Ah, tagged_with(). I forgot about that. I'll have to test it out soon.